# How do you plot a graph consisting of extracted entries from a nested list?

Tags: plot, list-comprehension, python-3.4, nested-lists

I have a nested list such that;

```
nested_list = [[4, 3, 0], [6, 8, 7], [3, 1, 8], [2, 1, 3], [9, 9, 3],  ...]
```

which has 100 entries.

I need to plot a graph of all the *first* elements of each sub-list where

```
Sub_List_1 = [4, 6, 3, 2, 9, ...]
```

against all the *third* elements of each sub-list where

```
Sub_List_2 = [0, 7, 8, 3, 3, ...]
```

over all the sub-lists, but I have no idea how to do this.

This is what I have tried:

```
k=0
while k<=100:
    x=nested_list[0][0][k]
    y=nested_list[k][0][0]
    k=+1
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.axis('image')
plt.show()
```

This does not work however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build two new lists. You can do this with list comprehensions:

```
x = [sub[0] for sub in nested_list]
y = [sub[2] for sub in nested_list]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Your code tried to access one level of nesting too many (you can only address `nested_list[k][0]`, not `nested_list[k][0][0]`) or tried to index the first value of the first nested list to index `k`. You also did not build new lists; you simply rebound `x` and `y` `k` times.

Comment: Hi you've been really helpful with this, so thank you. I suppose this is pushing my luck and I may have to ask it as a separate question, but the question you just answered was just a simple case to help me solve something more complicated. I now need to know how to implement this with non-integers and for almost infinite lists. But I will ask this as a separate question.